# Installing Android app on more devices problem

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

I have an app that have been published on play store and I am going to invite other people to install it by clicking on or pasting the link like this "**http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=<package_name>**" to browser.

I expected the people would see my app on Play Store app and could install it normally after having launched this link in browser but it wasn't. Only some devices can open Play Store app directly but some others have just displayed like this (I got the screenshot from a Xiaomi device)

[image]

I have clicked on the button "Install on more devices" and follow the next steps (eg sign in google account and whatever). Then I have just received the message that app will be installed on your device soon and the app is not installed.

How can I solve this matter?

Answer (score 0):

Your Google Play Links should look something like this `http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=<package_name>`.

If you want them to be opened by the Play Store App just do the following:

```
market://details?id=<package_name>
```

This Link should be opened by the Play Store directly.

For further studies read:
[This](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/22189/link-to-app-will-not-open-in-google-play)

Comment: Nice reference! But it seems not what I need for my problem. Pardon me for my bad description. Could you please check my update in the question again?

Comment: So if I understand that correctly: You have an App in the Store that ist in the closed Alpha/Beta (where you invite max. 100 people) and they can not install your app when clicking on the Link, because it "does not show up" or is not visible for them? (If i didn't understand please help me and provide more detail to your question)

Comment: I have realized the true problem I got and tried to update my question again. Please re-check it and feel free to ask more if there are any unclear information. Thank you